# Visual Basic - After checking a few checkboxes, how to appropriately include comma ",", fullstop "." And "and" in the output for VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm in my first year doing IT and currently am studying Visual Basic using Visual Basic Studio creating a Windows Form App. I am trying to create a form that will accept inputs from the user such as their name, age, gender, course, interests, and athletic level and the output should be as following.

**Taufiq Jusoff** is a **32** years old **Male**.

**He** is studying **Didn't**.

**He** is an **Extreme** level athlete.

**His** sports interests include;
Running, Walking, and Hiking. <-------- //This is where my problem is. I can't produce this output.

User input as String for name = Taufiq Jusoff

If a user enters a number or any non character, the system will prompt a message box asking to include only uppercase, and lowercase letters.

User input as Integer for age = 32

By default, there is no value listed just an empty text box.
If a user enters a value zero (0) or less, a message box will appear asking to key in a value between 1 - 99.

Radio button option for gender = Male <------------//the other problem I face

By default, there is no option selected.

If male is selected, the sentence output will display He or His in specific locations.

If female is selected, the sentence output will display She or Her in specific locations.
If they try to generate an output but no option is selected, a messagbox will prompt to select their gender.

Radio button option for course = Didn't
by default, none is selected.
If they try to generate an output without selecting, a messagebox will appear asking to select a course.

Radio button option for athletic level = Extreme

By default, non is selected.
If they try to generate an output without selecting, a messagebox will appear asking to select a course.

**Ideally I would like all these errors to appear in a single messagebox meaning the program will check and have the error messages compiled together.

Checkbox with multiple options = Running, Walking, and Hiking.

1. If item checked is none, the value becomes null.
2. If 1 item is checked, the end of the item becomes a full stop.
3. If 2 items are checked, the word "and " appears after the first item, and a full stop "." Appears after the second checked item.
4. If 3 or more items are checked, all the items until the 3rd last item will have a comma ",", the second last item will have a "and ", and the last item will have a full stop ".".

Desired outcome example.

1 item checked -
His sports interests are;
Running.

2 item checked -
His sports interests are;
Running and Walking.

3 items are checked -
His sports interests are;
Running, Walking, and Biking.

4 items or more are checked -
His sports interests are;
Running, Walking, Biking, and Swimming.

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

            Dim StName As String
            Dim IntAge As Integer
            Dim StCourse As String
            Dim stGender As String
            Dim stLevel As String
            Dim str As String

            StName = txtboxName.Text
            IntAge = txtboxAge.Text
            StCourse = " "
            stGender = " "
            stLevel = " "
            str = " "

            If chkboxRunning.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxRunning.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If chkboxWalking.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxWalking.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If chkboxBiking.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxBiking.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If chkboxSwimming.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxSwimming.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If chkboxIceSkating.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxIceSkating.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If chkboxFootball.Checked Then
                str &= chkboxFootball.Text
                str &= " "
            End If

            If rbtnMale.Checked Then
                stGender = rbtnMale.Text
            ElseIf rbtnFemale.Checked Then
                stGender = rbtnFemale.Text
            End If

            If rbtnDIT.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnDIT.Text
            ElseIf rbtnDCF.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnDCF.Text
            ElseIf rbtnDBC.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnDBC.Text
            ElseIf rbtnDMWT.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnDMWT.Text
            ElseIf rbtnDIFM.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnDIFM.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBSC.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBSC.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBBC.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBBC.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBCF.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBCF.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBICT.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBICT.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBMWT.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBMWT.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBFSA.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBFSA.Text
            ElseIf rbtnBIFM.Checked Then
                StCourse = rbtnBIFM.Text
            End If

            If btnradExtreme.Checked Then
                stLevel = btnradExtreme.Text
            ElseIf rbtnFemale.Checked Then
                stLevel = btnradAdvanced.Text
            ElseIf btnRadIntermediate.Checked Then
                stLevel = btnradIntermediate.Text
            ElseIf btnRadBeginner.Checked Then
                stLevel = btnradBeginner.Text
            End If


            Form2.show()

            Form2.txtboxDisplay.Text = StName & " is a " & IntAge & " year old " & stGender & "." & vbCrLf & "He is studying " & StCourse & "." & vbCrLf & "He is an " & stLevel & " level athlete." & vbCrLf & "His sports interests are; " & vbCrLf & str

        End Sub
```

Sample Ouput:
[image: Sample Ouput] - Here's how my program looks like and how I've done so far.

I'm keen to learn how this can produce an output based on the checkboxes. If I could get references on how I might be able to achieve this would be much appreciated. I've seen another post similar to this but I can't figure this out. My apologies if the post is too lengthy I just want to make sure I've covered as much information and background on this.

Comment: Your project is done, move to the next one.  After a while you'll learn that a data entry form like this is useful to add a record to a database, chatty text isn't.

Comment: There really isn't anything magical about this.  You have two or three special cases (no interests, one interest, two interests if using an Oxford comma) and one general case (two or more without Oxford comma, more than two with).  In the general case, you want to join all but the last with ", " and then manually put `", and "` or `" and "` (depending on whether you want the Oxford comma or not) before the last.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have those `CheckBoxes` in a `GroupBox`, in which case you can do something like this:

```vb
Dim interestList = myGroupBox.Controls.
                              OfType(Of CheckBox)().
                              Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).
                              Select(Function(cb) cb.Text).
                              ToArray()
Dim interests As String

Select Case checkedBoxes.Length
    Case 0:
        interests = String.Empty
    Case 1:
        interests = interestList(0) & "."
    Case 2:
        interests = $"{interestList(0)} and {interestList(1)}."
    Case Else:
        Dim upperBound = interestList.GetUperBound(0)

        interestList(upperBound) = "and " & interestList(upperBound)
        interests = String.Join(", ", interestList) & "."
End Select
```